# Can I post redesigns of album covers in my portfolio online?

Tags: copyright, legal, portfolio

Former student in graphic design, I am currently working on personal projects to widen my portfolio.

I love to design album covers. I never had clients for that, so I have been re-designing real albums from real artists. I was wondering if I can post these personal projects on my website knowing that these albums actually exist and that my design is not the official one (regarding the artist who originally designed the cover). Would it be even legal?

Comment: Other similar questions: [Is it legally ok to show concepts for existing companies?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65547/23061) and [Can I use company logos in my portfolio?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/49395/23061). It might be helpful for GD.SE to have a canonical Q&A for what's able to be included in a portfolio.

Comment: I'd think this could be covered under the same rules as fan-art… but I'm not a lawyer. The only thing you took was the name; which is copyright, but band names & titles get re-used all the time.

Comment: @ZachSaucier It helps, thank you ! It seems more prudent not to post them, I don't want to take any risks.